# Interpretation of "[Numbers] are taken modulo" in scientific writing and best practice suggestions

Tags: modular-arithmetic, article-writing

This is a question specific to scientific writing and not about the modulo operation. The final question will be: *Is this expression well-formed, or should it come with clarification?*

On several occasions I read something like "indices are taken modulo $N$" in scientific publications. These usually follow a math expression like

$$
f(\vec{x},k) = x_{i+k}\,\hat{e}_i,
$$

where the key is that $\vec{x}$ lives in a finite dimensional space, let's say of dimension $N$ and thus in index $i+k >N$ would not be defined.

When the authors say *take the index modulo $N$*, I assume most times they mean: if $i+k = m > N$, then assign $m\rightarrow m-N$, because most times the index will run from $1$ to $N$. This of course is not the usual way of applying the modulo operation, which would have a $\geq$ - symbol in the above condition. To me it is perfectly clear what is meant by the instruction to take the index modulo $N$ and I know that sometimes we rely on the good-willed nature of a reader.

My question thus is: **Is this (strictly speaking) inaccurancy in the definition of mathematical expressions acceptable in the context of scientific writing style or should it be further clarified?**
And as a follow up: Would you recommend a different formulation? Which?

Some remarks:

- You can assume for the purpose of this question that the number that is taken modulo $N$ is supposed to take on the value $N$ and not zero if $i+k=N$. It also does not have to be an index, but they might be a special case.
- Further, the example above is simply that - an example. I am not asking about that specifically.
- If it matters, I am reading publications from an interdisciplinary field (pulse-coupled oscillators) mainly between applied mathematics and physics. Readers could be from both the Mathematics or Physics world, or possibly even Engineering, Neuroscience or Biology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware that *modulo* has two meanings:

- it is an operator that returns an integer in the range $[0,n-1]$, so that $n\bmod n=0$.
- it is also an argument to the congruence relation $\equiv$; in that sense, $0\equiv n\equiv 2n\cdots\mod n$.

The second meaning is compatible with the reduction $1\to1,2\to2\cdots n-1\to n-1,n\to n,n+1\to1,n+2\to2,\cdots$ as well as with
$1\to1,2\to2\cdots n-1\to n-1,n\to 0,n+1\to1,n+2\to2,\cdots$

In any case, I will always understand this *modulo $n$* as the shifting by a multiple of $n$ that clamps the index back to the allowed range.